# Post Request 500 Error Python Requests Web Scraping

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, http-post

I've scraped many sites in the past using the requests library and the methodology I use here but for some reason, this site keeps returning a 500 error despite the fact I can access information in the browser.

Here is a link to progressive's job board for all of their IT openings: https://progressive.taleo.net/careersection/2/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en#

here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json


url = "https://progressive.taleo.net/careersection/rest/jobboard/searchjobs?lang=en&portal=101430233"

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36',
}


# headers = {
#   'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
#   'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
#   'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store',
#   'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
#   'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
#   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
#   'Origin': 'https://progressive.taleo.net',
#   'Referer': 'https://progressive.taleo.net/careersection/2/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en',
#   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36',
#   'Host': 'progressive.taleo.net',
#   'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
#   'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
# }

data = '{"multilineEnabled":false,"sortingSelection":{"sortBySelectionParam":"3","ascendingSortingOrder":"false"},"fieldData":{"fields":{"KEYWORD":"","JOB_TITLE":"","JOB_NUMBER":""},"valid":true},"filterSelectionParam":{"searchFilterSelections":[{"id":"POSTING_DATE","selectedValues":[]},{"id":"LOCATION","selectedValues":["213860137526","209460137526"]},{"id":"JOB_FIELD","selectedValues":["4460472188"]},{"id":"JOB_SCHEDULE","selectedValues":[]}]},"advancedSearchFiltersSelectionParam":{"searchFilterSelections":[{"id":"ORGANIZATION","selectedValues":[]},{"id":"LOCATION","selectedValues":[]},{"id":"JOB_FIELD","selectedValues":[]},{"id":"URGENT_JOB","selectedValues":[]},{"id":"EMPLOYEE_STATUS","selectedValues":[]}]},"pageNo":1}'

def test_post(url):
    dirty = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    print(dirty.headers)
    print(dirty.status_code)
    # clean = json.loads(dirty)
    # print(clean)

test_post(url)
```

Using Chrome tools you can view the XHR requests and see that you can send a post request to the url within my code, and it should return a JSON object with all of the job openings. Instead, I keep getting a 500 error with no specific information other than 'Request Failed' or something to that affect.

If someone could shed some light on the problem I would greatly appreciate it. I want to be able to scrape all the job titles from the site.

P.S. I left the commented section because I also included other headers and none seemed to work.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Once I get a chance to try it I'll upvote your response. One thing that I don't fully understand is why you sometimes need to include this information and other times you don't. Why does the time zone matter in this particular instance? Or how can you determine what you need and don't need based off of the headers given to you in inspection?

Comment: In this particular instance the `tz` header is needed. My guess is that the code behind this web-page tries to read it and errors (500s) if it can not be read. To determine what headers are needed for a particular web-page in Firefox right click on the page, select `Inspect Element` select `Network` refresh the page  right click on the request you want select `Copy` then `Copy as cURL` paste what you copied into https://curl.trillworks.com/ then use the generated code, if it works remove headers one at a time until you get a minimal set that works.

Comment: You can also try removing the cookie as well to see if it is needed or not. The process using Chrome is very similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to set he `time zone` header:

```
import requests

url = "https://progressive.taleo.net/careersection/rest/jobboard/searchjobs?lang=en&portal=101430233"

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'tz': 'GMT+00:00',
}

data = '{"multilineEnabled":false,"sortingSelection":{"sortBySelectionParam":"3","ascendingSortingOrder":"false"},"fieldData":{"fields":{"KEYWORD":"","JOB_TITLE":"","JOB_NUMBER":""},"valid":true},"filterSelectionParam":{"searchFilterSelections":[{"id":"POSTING_DATE","selectedValues":[]},{"id":"LOCATION","selectedValues":["213860137526","209460137526"]},{"id":"JOB_FIELD","selectedValues":["4460472188"]},{"id":"JOB_SCHEDULE","selectedValues":[]}]},"advancedSearchFiltersSelectionParam":{"searchFilterSelections":[{"id":"ORGANIZATION","selectedValues":[]},{"id":"LOCATION","selectedValues":[]},{"id":"JOB_FIELD","selectedValues":[]},{"id":"URGENT_JOB","selectedValues":[]},{"id":"EMPLOYEE_STATUS","selectedValues":[]}]},"pageNo":1}'


def test_post(url):
    dirty = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    print(dirty.headers)
    print(dirty.status_code)
    clean = dirty.json()
    print(clean)

test_post(url)
```

Outputs:

```
{'Date': 'Sun, 22 Dec 2019 00:48:53 GMT', 'Server': 'Taleo Web Server 8', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Expires': '-1', 'P3P': 'CP="CAO PSA OUR"', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Set-Cookie': 'locale=en; path=/careersection/', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1', 'X-UA-Compatible': 'IE=edge', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5, max=100', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
200
{'requisitionList': [{'hotJob': True, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '810924', 'contestNo': '161749', 'column': ['Big Data Lead Developer', '["Multiple Locations"]', 'Dec 6, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '834485', 'contestNo': '164658', 'column': ['DevOps Engineer Senior or Lead - Big Data', '["United States-Ohio-Mayfield Village"]', 'Dec 20, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '834269', 'contestNo': '164625', 'column': ['IT Systems Analyst Senior/Lead – Enterprise Services Operations Center', '["Multiple Locations"]', 'Dec 20, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '832904', 'contestNo': '164433', 'column': ['Data Warehouse Developer', '["Multiple Locations"]', 'Dec 19, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '827706', 'contestNo': '163768', 'column': ['Quality Assurance Analyst', '["Multiple Locations"]', 'Dec 18, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '831205', 'contestNo': '164213', 'column': ['BI Developer to BI Developer Senior', '["United States-Ohio-Mayfield Heights"]', 'Dec 18, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '832344', 'contestNo': '164360', 'column': ['Software Developer Senior / Lead', '["United States-Ohio-Mayfield Village"]', 'Dec 18, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '830766', 'contestNo': '164139', 'column': ['Developer QA Analyst', '["United States-Ohio-Mayfield Heights"]', 'Dec 17, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '833006', 'contestNo': '164460', 'column': ['Business Systems Analyst Senior or Lead - ASWP', '["United States-Ohio-Mayfield Village"]', 'Dec 17, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '831704', 'contestNo': '164255', 'column': ['Software Developer Lead', '["United States-Ohio-Mayfield Village"]', 'Dec 17, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '807764', 'contestNo': '161418', 'column': ['Business Systems Analyst (Sr or Lead) - CRM', '["Multiple Locations"]', 'Dec 16, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '832230', 'contestNo': '164349', 'column': ['Software Developer / Senior / Lead', '["Multiple Locations"]', 'Dec 16, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '831664', 'contestNo': '164247', 'column': ['Business Systems Analyst Intermediate to Senior - Mobile Native Apps', '["Multiple Locations"]', 'Dec 15, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '825524', 'contestNo': '163476', 'column': ['Software Developer / Senior', '["Multiple Locations"]', 'Dec 14, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '831264', 'contestNo': '164215', 'column': ['BI Developer to BI Developer Senior', '["United States-Ohio-Mayfield Heights"]', 'Dec 13, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '831484', 'contestNo': '164236', 'column': ['Full Stack Developer - Enterprise Resource Organization', '["Multiple Locations"]', 'Dec 13, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '832004', 'contestNo': '164304', 'column': ['Network IT Systems Engineer Senior for WAN/Carrier', '["Multiple Locations"]', 'Dec 11, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '830304', 'contestNo': '164085', 'column': ['Business Systems Analyst Sr.', '["Multiple Locations"]', 'Dec 9, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '829325', 'contestNo': '163974', 'column': ['Quality Assurance Analyst Senior or Lead', '["Multiple Locations"]', 'Nov 27, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '829125', 'contestNo': '163961', 'column': ['Software Developer / Senior', '["Multiple Locations"]', 'Nov 26, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '827944', 'contestNo': '163802', 'column': ['Quality Assurance Analyst Senior', '["United States-Ohio-Mayfield Village"]', 'Nov 25, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '827686', 'contestNo': '163774', 'column': ['Quality Assurance Test Lead', '["United States-Ohio-Mayfield Village"]', 'Nov 25, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '826384', 'contestNo': '163601', 'column': ['Software Developer Senior / Lead', '["Multiple Locations"]', 'Nov 25, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '825644', 'contestNo': '163496', 'column': ['IT DevOps Engineer Lead', '["Multiple Locations"]', 'Nov 13, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}, {'hotJob': False, 'addedToJobCart': False, 'draft': False, 'alreadyAppliedOn': False, 'toReApply': False, 'jobId': '824252', 'contestNo': '163292', 'column': ['Systems Test Engineer Intermediate to Senior', '["Multiple Locations"]', 'Nov 8, 2019'], 'linkedColumn': 0, 'locationsColumns': [1]}], 'facetResults': [{'id': 'POSTING_DATE', 'facetValueResults': [{'id': '1', 'text': 'Today', 'quantity': ''}, {'id': '2', 'text': 'Yesterday', 'quantity': ''}, {'id': '3', 'text': 'Last 7 Days', 'quantity': ''}, {'id': '4', 'text': 'Last 14 Days', 'quantity': ''}, {'id': '5', 'text': 'Last 21 Days', 'quantity': ''}, {'id': '6', 'text': 'Last 28 Days', 'quantity': ''}]}, {'id': 'LOCATION', 'facetValueResults': [{'id': '209460137526', 'text': 'Mayfield Village', 'quantity': '23', 'level': 3}, {'id': '213860137526', 'text': 'Mayfield Heights', 'quantity': '3', 'level': 3}], 'levelList': [{'level': 1, 'name': 'Country'}, {'level': 2, 'name': 'State'}, {'level': 3, 'name': 'City'}, {'level': 4, 'name': 'Work Location'}]}, {'id': 'JOB_FIELD', 'facetValueResults': [{'id': '4460472188', 'text': 'Information Technology', 'quantity': '26', 'level': 1}], 'levelList': [{'level': 1, 'name': 'Job Category'}]}, {'id': 'JOB_SCHEDULE', 'facetValueResults': [{'id': '1', 'text': 'Full-time', 'quantity': '26'}]}, {'id': 'JOB_LOCALE', 'facetValueResults': [{'id': 'en', 'text': 'English (26)', 'quantity': '26'}]}], 'pagingData': {'currentPageNo': 1, 'pageSize': 25, 'totalCount': 26}, 'queryString': 'f=LOCATION(213860137526,209460137526)|JOB_FIELD(4460472188)&s=3|D&a=null&multiline=false', 'careerSectionUnAvailable': False, 'supportedLanguages': []}
```